# FB OpenGraph og:image is not pulling images even if URL is rendering correctly

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

FB OpenGraph og:image is not pulling images even if URL is rendering correctly. But next time if we share the same URL, then it pickup the correct image. Also to add, we have added multiple og:image tags (4 tags to be specific) to ensure that one of the images is picked up. It is picking the last og:image tag but if we share the same URL link the correct Image is shown i.e. the first og:image tag. Please suggest.
For multiple og:image meta tags we are using http and https images URLs

Comment: Which platform are you working on? provide more information about your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger an update to the scraped information by hitting

```
POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

if the content was changed. Also, you can use the URL debugger to see what Facebook scrapes for your URL

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/